# program codings for record videos and store in my database for android app?

Tags: java, android, database, video-capture

> how the video can record by using camcorder and store in SQLite ?

Android: Record video in the same orientation regardless of device orientation

- How to get size of movie that i'm capturing and update the screen during capture?
- Is it possible to use CamcorderProfile without audio source?
- How to protect read/copy/delete video files?